# Get Live updates from Webpage using C# WebClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, live

I am developing a Windows Phone app in which I am parsing a webpage from my website. Where some games score updated live, like in cricinfo. Anybody tell me how I sync my webpage with my windows phone WebClient request so that I get updated score wihtout request or refershing in my windows phone app. I am using HTML agility pack and Webclient for parsing html page of mine site.

Comment: Why not using some kind of WebService ? Or maybe is the webpage not hosted by you ?

Comment: "How I [use] WebClient so that I [do something] without request" Hmm. That's going to be a tricky problem to solve.

Comment: Yes web page is not hosted by me. But I am getting its content. is there anyway of autorefresh to get update if webpage has changes in its content.

Comment: So, let's be clear... you want a 3rd party website (that is out of your control) to provide you with push-notifications when its content changes?

Comment: How does the website update itself usually? It probably just has a periodic auto refresh and you can do the same.

Comment: Don't do this.  Even if you do get it working, as soon as the structure of the source webpage changes, it'll break.  See the suggestion by @Hybris95.  Either expose a web service (or REST endpoint) from your website, or find a third party that exposes one.

Comment: Hmmm: "I am parsing a webpage from **my** website", "**my** webpage", "parsing html page of **mine** site" vs. "Yes web page is not hosted by me".

Answer (score 0):

If the webpage is hosted by a third-party which seems to be the case. Except if there is some kind of RSS-Flow you will have to manually refresh regulary your application.
So all you have to do, is refreshing the information inside some loop with a defined interval.

If the webpage is hosted by you, I suggest using some kind of webservice to recover such information.